# Fresco : Display Wrong image in gridview

Tags: android, baseadapter, fresco

I am using gridview. In grid each item contain a simpledraweeview, when i add a new item in first place and notify the adapter at that time first and last item having the same image. **(It only occur in below lollipop)**

**XML SimpleDraweeView :**

```
<com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                android:id="@+id/id_imageview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
               android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/COM_NOTEBOOK_NOTEBOOK"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                app:imageUrl="@{url}" />
```

**Image loading code :**

```
public void justLoadImage(final String mPath, final SimpleDraweeView mImageView, int width, int height) {
    try {

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mPath) || mImageView == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (!isBitmapAvailableInMemCache(mPath)) {
            GenericDraweeHierarchy hierarchy = setHierarchyForDraweeView(mImageView, 150);
            hierarchy.setPlaceholderImage(mAsyncColorDrawable);
            hierarchy.setFailureImage(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.broken_image_black));
        }

        ImageRequest request;
        if (mPath.endsWith(".jpg")) {//No i18n
            request = ImageRequestBuilder.newBuilderWithSource(Uri.fromFile(new File(mPath)))
                    .setLocalThumbnailPreviewsEnabled(true)
                    .setResizeOptions(new ResizeOptions(width, height))
                    .build();
        } else {
            request = ImageRequestBuilder.newBuilderWithSource(Uri.fromFile(new File(mPath)))
                    .setLocalThumbnailPreviewsEnabled(true)
                    .build();
        }

        DraweeController draweeController = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
                .setControllerListener(new ControllerListener<ImageInfo>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubmit(String id, Object callerContext) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinalImageSet(String id, @Nullable ImageInfo imageInfo, @Nullable Animatable animatable) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onIntermediateImageSet(String id, @Nullable ImageInfo imageInfo) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onIntermediateImageFailed(String id, Throwable throwable) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(String id, Throwable throwable) {
                        clearFerscoCache(mPath);
                        mImageView.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(new File(mPath)));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onRelease(String id) {

                    }
                })
                .setOldController(mImageView.getController())
                .setImageRequest(request)
                .setAutoPlayAnimations(false)
                .build();
        mImageView.setController(draweeController);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError | Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**SetHierarchyForDraweeView Function**

```
 private GenericDraweeHierarchy setHierarchyForDraweeView(SimpleDraweeView draweeView, int duration) {
    if (draweeView != null) {
        if (draweeView.getHierarchy() == null) {
            GenericDraweeHierarchyBuilder builder = new GenericDraweeHierarchyBuilder(mContext.getResources());
            GenericDraweeHierarchy hierarchy = builder
                    .setFadeDuration(duration)
                    .setPlaceholderImage(new AsyncColorDrawable(mContext.getResources()))
                    .setFailureImage(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.broken_image_black))
                    .build();
            draweeView.setHierarchy(hierarchy);
        } else {
            GenericDraweeHierarchy hierarchy = draweeView.getHierarchy();
            hierarchy.setFadeDuration(duration);
            return hierarchy;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `ViewHoler` pattern in your `GridView` adapter first condition in your if check in the lines below in your `justLoadImage` method can cause this kind if situation.

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mPath) || mImageView == null) {
            return;
}
```

So you simply can try to remove this lines and let Fresco to handle this situation or manually set an empty image to your `SimpleDraweeView` in your ViewHolder if imagePath is null.

**Edit:**

You can check logs. Getting an exception in your `justLoadImage` method also can cause this kind of situation.

Comment: Thanks. But in my case mPath and mImageView is always not null.